# Oriented Bounding Box Collision Issue

Tags: c++, collision, bounding-box

I'm trying to create OBB's around objects and then collide them using DirectX 11 and C++. It all works fine until I rotate one (or more) of the boxes and then the collision detection returns true too early. It seems to still "correctly" collide but just too early (as in bounding box is too big). I think I'm going wrong on the fundamentals so here's a quick breakdown of the steps I've done:

- Create a OBB struct that contains a Vector mCentre, Float[3] mExtents and Vector[3] mLocalAxes.
- I derive the centre by finding the "left" adding the half of the width, rinse and repeat for other axes.
- The extents are the "half widths" so width, height and depth / 2
- The local axes is taken from the top 3 rows of the matrix.
- I then use a function to check all 15 axes to test for a separating axis which returns false if one is found.

If anyone can see a flaw in my logic and point it out that'd be great! (I have a feeling my centre calculations are wrong)

Normally I would put up code but this is coursework so I'd much rather just find where my train of thought is wrong!

Thanks in advance (sorry for the wall of text)

Comment: So your code fails to find a separating plane, even when one exists. Now grab a failure case, confirm that the plane exists and see where the code ought to detect it.

Comment: Yeah I'm doing that and I'm struggling to see where it is going wrong, which leads me to believe it is my logic which is why I asked, is the steps above sound or am I misunderstanding something fundamental?